# How to interpret pointcloud topic "/kinect/depth/points" from openni_kinect library?

Tags: ros, gazebo-ros-openni-kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I search for a long time on wikis/forums... but i found nothing which fits to me.
I still don't know how to get coordinates x y z from every point in this topic, how many points they are and, possibly, RGB values.

**This is the content of a message in this topic:**

### header:
seq: 19
stamp:
secs: 124
nsecs: 110000000
frame_id: "camera_depth_optical_frame"
height: 480
width: 640
fields:

```
name: "x"
offset: 0
datatype: 7
count: 1
```

- name: "y"
  offset: 4
  datatype: 7
  count: 1
- name: "z"
  offset: 8
  datatype: 7
  count: 1
- name: "rgb"
  offset: 16
  datatype: 7
  count: 1
  is_bigendian: False
  point_step: 32
  row_step: 20480
  data:
  [0, 0, 192, 127, 0, 0, 192, 127, 0, 0, 192, 127, 0, 0, 0, 0, 178, 178, 178, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...]
  is_dense: False

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/394697/how-to-interpret-pointcloud-topic-%22/kinect/depth/points%22-from-openni_kinect-library?/) by [jvj00](https://answers.ros.org/users/94247/jvj00/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-01-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dembele123](https://answers.ros.org/users/54011/dembele123/) on 2022-01-20**:
If message is type *sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.msg* my advice would be to look pcl library.  The pcl library has a lot of implemented things for pointclouds.

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2022-01-22**:
Are you using roscpp or rospy?

**Comment by [jvj00](https://answers.ros.org/users/94247/jvj00/) on 2022-01-24**:
I'm using roscpp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @jvj00:

What you have here is a message of type" `sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.msg`:
Reference: http://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/PointCloud2.html

```
# This message holds a collection of N-dimensional points, which may
# contain additional information such as normals, intensity, etc. The
# point data is stored as a binary blob, its layout described by the
# contents of the "fields" array.

# The point cloud data may be organized 2d (image-like) or 1d
# (unordered). Point clouds organized as 2d images may be produced by
# camera depth sensors such as stereo or time-of-flight.

# Time of sensor data acquisition, and the coordinate frame ID (for 3d
# points).
Header header

# 2D structure of the point cloud. If the cloud is unordered, height is
# 1 and width is the length of the point cloud.
uint32 height
uint32 width

# Describes the channels and their layout in the binary data blob.
PointField[] fields

bool    is_bigendian # Is this data bigendian?
uint32  point_step   # Length of a point in bytes
uint32  row_step     # Length of a row in bytes
uint8[] data         # Actual point data, size is (row_step*height)

bool is_dense        # True if there are no invalid points
```

Let's break it a little further:
The header message is of type `std_msgs/Header.msg`

```
uint32 seq
time stamp
string frame_id
```

In your case: `header: seq: 19 stamp: secs: 124 nsecs: 110000000`

```
uint32 height
uint32 width
```

`frame_id: "camera_depth_optical_frame" height: 480 width: 640`

Then comes

```
PointField[] fields
```

`PointField[] fields` is of type `sensor_msgs/PointField.msg`

The `sensor_msgs/PointField.msg` is composed of:

```
# This message holds the description of one point entry in the
# PointCloud2 message format.
uint8 INT8    = 1
uint8 UINT8   = 2
uint8 INT16   = 3
uint8 UINT16  = 4
uint8 INT32   = 5
uint8 UINT32  = 6
uint8 FLOAT32 = 7
uint8 FLOAT64 = 8

string name      # Name of field
uint32 offset    # Offset from start of point struct
uint8  datatype  # Datatype enumeration, see above
uint32 count     # How many elements in the field
```

In your case: `fields: - name: "x" offset: 0 datatype: 7 count: 1 - name: "y" offset: 4 datatype: 7 count: 1 - name: "z" offset: 8 datatype: 7 count: 1`

`is_bigendian`, `point_step` and `row_step` and `is_dense` are straight forward to understand.

Finally,

```
uint8[] data
```

`data` contains the Actual point data, size is (row_step*height)
In your case: `data: [0, 0, 192, 127, 0, 0, 192, 127, 0, 0, 192, 127, 0, 0, 0, 0, 178, 178, 178, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...]`

If you like to learn how to read this point with code, refer to this tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/pcl/Tutorials

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2022-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jvj00](https://answers.ros.org/users/94247/jvj00/) on 2022-01-21**:
Thanks a lot! I'll try to write a program with this information that you give to me

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2022-01-21**:
Glad it helped. Kindly accept the answer by clicking on the check mark. Thank you.

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2022-01-22**:
@jvj00 You do not need to convert this PointCloud2 msg to "useful" form yourself, there is already standard code in `pcl_ros` to do it (although I feel it is documented poorly.) See Section 3.1 on this page: http://wiki.ros.org/pcl_ros?distro=noetic